# Change attribute table value using graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, qgis-modeler

So I have a **buffer layer** with an associated **attribute table**. This table has a column called "value" that I want to change to "x" based on previous selection. I can select the buffers in the layers I need to edit, but I don't know **how to edit the values of the attributes of the selected buffers**.

How can directly edit attribute values at a specific column from the graphical modeler?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use the **Field Calculator algorithm**.

[image]

There doesn't appear to be any documentation for this algorithm, except for [this](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#field-calculator). But it looks like it works like the regular Field Calculator. Choose a layer from the dropdown menu, type in the name of the field you want to modify, choose 'no' as the option for Create new field, and type in the expression you want to use to modify the field. If you need help writing the expression, use the help available in the regular Field Calculator.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without creating a new layer? I just want to edit an existing layer.

Comment: What do you mean? In a graphical modeller you pretty much go through the steps with a new layer at every step.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Refactor fields` tool for this.

Here I loaded the existing fields from the `1111` layer and then:

- Convert the type of the field "`status`" to string
- Add a new field "`new_field`" with the static value '`hi`'
- Add a new field "`km_str`" with the value of the "`km`" field converted to string

[image]